# Renaming columns with ' in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, multiple-columns, rename

How to rename column "RANDY'S" to 'RANDYS' in pyspark?

I tried below code and its not working

```
test_rename_df=df.withColumnRenamed('"RANDY''S"','RANDYS')
```

Note that original column name has double quotes around it

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2Jjg.png)

Comment: based on the screenshot, i don't think the column name has `"` around it. spark used the double quotes as it couldn't use the single quotes (which is the default). you can simply try `withColumnRenamed("RANDY'S", 'RANDYS')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding too many quotes around the original column name. Try this:

```py
test_rename_df = df.withColumnRenamed("RANDY\'S", "RANDYS")
```

### Side-note

When you call `df.columns`, the column `RANDY'S` is surrounded by double quotes instead of single quotes to avoid confusion.

If your column had the name `RANDY"S`, `df.columns` would instead use single quotes around the column name (see screenshot below):

[image]